# this css not working for radio button selection

Tags: html, css, radio-button

in following jsfiddle, I am trying to change the color of selected radio button for two (or more) different radio groups, by only using CSS. I am missing something i do not know.

http://jsfiddle.net/2nxnk/1/

CODE:

```
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="1" /> One
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="2" /> Two
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="3" /> Three
<p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="4" /> Four
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="5" /> Five
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="6" /> Six
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked{ color: green; }
```

i do not want to use any jquery unless there is no other way. pl advice.

EDIT:
I decided to edit the question: I want to change the color of 'text of radio button'. secondly i did not want to clutter the html page with ID's if the only use is to change text color. My question now is:
1. is using the label only way?
2. seems using IDs you get capability of coloring different radio group (text again) differently. is that correct?
3. finally maybe a simple question: I though only javascript catches the action on the page, when there is no javascript how does CSS triggers the effect?

thx all for help and I also upped the last example which colors the radio button image itself.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://www.andreapinchi.it/how-to-style-radio-buttons-with-pure-css/

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the button itself or the text next to it?

Comment: `color != background-color`.

Comment: You must explain the question better. Do you want to change the appearance of the radio itself or the color of the text next to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the text next to the radio button, you can do this way

#### Html

```
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="1" /><label>One</label>
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="2" /><label>Two</label> 
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="3" /><label>Three</label> 
<p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="4" /><label>Four</label> 
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="5" /><label>Five</label> 
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="6" /><label>Six</label>
```

#### Css

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    color: green;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHnGu/)

Probably pseudo element can help a bit:-

```
input[type="radio"]:checked +label {
    color: green;
  }

input[type="radio"]:checked:before
{
 content:'.';
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:green;
 width:12px;
 opacity:.3;
 top:-1px;
 border-radius:10px;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5PV7/)

Comment: The OP mentioned no labels. This might not be what he's after at all.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Yup OP did not mention about labels, but it is always a  good way to use labels to display radio text. Also this is just an additional option as it is known color of the button cannot be changed. Also by the way where is color applied on a button. it is applied on text content, so not sure if OP was looking for coloring the text.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks What's bad in suggesting `labels`? They are used for these purposes, so why not use them? OP's come with an issue, making it right is our job, do you upvote answers who just fix the issue or do you upvote answer which fixes the issue and gives him few more refactoring tips?

Comment: Guys how about using `:before` pseudo element?

Comment: @PSL While technically the color of the radio buttons cannot be changed directly, they can be changed using some work-arounds. While Javascript would work the best, I have provided a pure CSS solution to changing the color of the radio buttons below.

Comment: what is the checked:before doing? I looked at the fiddle without the checked:before block and it still worked.

Comment: @rajeev it is pseudo element in CSS, it adds a pseudo element before the mentioned item. if you want to make it work in all brosers you can add it on the label (making pseudo element relative) and some little work on the positioning and border radius. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Answer (score 2):

In most (if not all) browsers, you cannot change the colour of a radio button at all.

You can only simulate it by replacing the radio button with a different widget and trying to link it to the real radio button so it continues to work. Most implementations of this depend on JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change the color of the text if respective radio button is selected, you can use `+` adjacent selector and wrap the text inside a `label` tag

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label { 
   color: green; 
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ShXgm/)

I've removed other boxes to decrease the clutter, but logic goes same for else

Comment: Where in the question does it mention labels?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Question doesn't mention labels, I suggest using labels

Comment: @PSL :D Oh yes I see that coming, just the thing is I got rid of a long list of radios ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider making your own radio boxes? Using `label`s that is

We can make labels act like radio boxes by using the "for" attribute, which then makes it clickable and react to the `:checked` selector. The best thing about these is a label is a basic HTML element so  you can make it look exactly as you intend. Check this relatively plain example:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2nxnk/7/)

```
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="1" id="one"/> 
<label for="one"><div class="inner"></div></label><span>One</span>
<input type="radio" name="group0" value="2" id="two"/> 
<label for="two"><div class="inner"></div></label><span>Two</span>


input {
    display: none;
}

span, 
label {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    float: left;
}

label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

input:checked + label{
    background: green;
}

.inner {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code here? ;) You've a wonderful solution but will be of no use once the link is dead

Comment: This is just getting awesome and awesome, btw instead of label why don't you use span? this way you'll preserve the label for additional functionality

Comment: Yes I know that, and that's why I told you to use background for span instead of label :)

Comment: Yes, but I just suggested so that label can be used as it should be ;)

Answer (score 1):

***Update***

Here is a new fiddle with the actual buttons like I was referring to. 
Link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFgw8/2/)

Others have answered how to change the text, which I believe is what you are looking for based on your attempt. But, in the off chance you are looking to change the appearance of the button itself you could use `<label for="#id">` and some CSS styling/opacity tricks to replace the buttons with images. Then, change the background color when checked. My example and fiddle use placekittens, but you could substitute the `<img>` sources with any image you wanted (a colored radio button with 50% opacity for example would allow you to disregard the `opacity` section of code.) See my code below and this ***[fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DFgw8/)*** You'll have to play with the `margin` and `padding` settings to make the background color canvas the entire image, but this should give you an idea.

HTML

```
<input id="a" type="radio" name="group0" value="1" />
  <label for="a"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/40/40" /></label>
<input id="b" type="radio" name="group0" value="2" />
  <label for="b"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/40/39" /></label>
<input id="c" type="radio" name="group0" value="3" />
  <label for="c"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/39/40" /></label>
<p>
<input id="d" type="radio" name="group1" value="4" />
  <label for="d"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/38/40" /></label>
<input id="e" type="radio" name="group1" value="5" />
  <label for="e"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/40/38" /></label>
<input id="f" type="radio" name="group1" value="6" />
  <label for="f"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/39/38" /></label>
```

CSS

```
input {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: green;
}
img {
  opacity:0.4;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Not that it's the end of the world or anything, I just want to make sure I don't make the same mistake again... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can set css like that for a radio button.

BUT! you can set:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Maybe change the background color?

But that's about as much as you can change, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In case that you are already using Bootstrap (both CSS and JavaScript) you could use class selector `active` to achieve effect like the one you want.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7k0dbgsa/1/

```
.active
{
    color: green;
}
```

*The fiddle has been forked from https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0nevkwyn/*